# Firebase Test Labs Android Instrumented Test. How can I run each device sequentially. Not simultaneously

Tags: android, firebase-test-lab, instrumented-test

Our app only allows 1 user to be actively logged in at any given time.

If the same user attempts to log into another device, that user will be logged out of the previous device.

Is it possible to have Firebase Test Labs Instrumented Test run each device sequentially?  Not simultaneously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serial or Parallel: Device testing order on Robo Test Lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419361/serial-or-parallel-device-testing-order-on-robo-test-lab)

Comment: Thanks, Malik.  Unfortunately, it doesn't.  We are looking to have each device in the test group go one after the other.  Not at the same time.  Any ideas to how we might be able to setup this up?

Comment: Also, any idea how to reopen my question without redoing it?

Comment: I think the other questions answers this. This is not a supported feature in Firebase Test Lab. If you want that behavior than you need to manage this synchronization yourself, by testing on one device after another. (Doing one test run, wait for it to pass or fail, then do another test run).

Comment: Yes, I can manually sit and create one new test after another.  But the idea is to automate this.   The goal would be to setup one test with a selected group of devices, so that we don't have to sit and watch each test run the create a new test.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: I understand your requirements, but this is not supported in Firebase Test Lab. There's no option in Test Lab today that would allow you to do this. If you really need this feature, you need to solve it outside of Test Lab. E.g. via a shell script that runs a test on one device after another.